# PHP strpos problem

Tags: php, curl, strpos

I have a script that's fetching a page from a site using cURL and im trying to cut it up row by row then extracting what i need and removing that row. The problem is, sometimes it will give me the correct position of an item and sometimes it wont depending on what row, it alternates.

im trying to use one of these pages: http://www.gametracker.com/search/

the code im using is:

```
while (strpos($contents, '<tr>'))
{
    $start = strpos($contents, '<tr>');
    $end = strpos($contents, '</tr>', $start) + 5;
    $rstring = substr($contents, $start, $end - $start);
    $contents = str_replace($rstring, '', $contents);
    //nameee
        $start = strpos($rstring, '[clantag]');
    $end = strpos($rstring, '</a>', $start);
    $name= trim(substr($rstring, $start, $end - $start));
    echo $name . '<br/>';
        //players
    $search = '<td class="c05 item_bgcolor_even">';
        $start = (strpos($rstring, $search) + strlen($search));
    $end = strpos($rstring, "</td>", $start);
    $players= trim(substr($rstring, $start, ($end - $start)));
    echo $players . '<br />';
    $map;
    $curPlayers;
    $maxPlayers;
    $ip;
}
```

It gets the server name correctly but when it comes to players, one line i get them and the other I get lor_odd"> 1230.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be way easier with a [DOM parser](http://php.net/dom):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.gametracker.com/search/');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Get the rows from the search list
$rows = $xpath->query('//table[@class="table_lst table_lst_srs"]/tr');

for ($i=1; $i<$rows->length-1; $i++) {
    $row = $rows->item($i);

    // Get the columns for a row
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

    // Get the server name (3rd column)
    echo 'Name: '.trim($cols->item(2)->textContent).PHP_EOL;

    // Get the player count (5th column)
    echo 'Players: '.trim($cols->item(4)->textContent).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Name: NoobonicPlague.com | 24/7 RP, FastDL, Custom Mods
Players: 55/65

Name: RUS Coop-20 Semantic #1 (2.0.7.0)
Players: 20/20

Name: TAW.net -(Dallas)
Players: 32/32

Name: Dedicated
Players: 0/12

...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I had no idea it could be done in a way that's so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have been writing the "wrong" kind of code for such processing. It's difficult to understand and to maintain, let alone to debug.

If you are willing to scrap the manual HTML parsing and use [XPath](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html) queries instead, your life will become *much* easier:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($contents); // $contents = the HTML that curl returns

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// You can now use as many XPath queries as you like; they look like this:
$nodes = $xpath->query(''); // you own query expression here
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $v = $node->nodeValue; // now do something with $v
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it's hard to understand but I was just testing to see if I could actually rip out everything i needed, using a dom parser turned out to be much easier though. Thanks.